# Inherit configurations from a basic-language in monaco-editor

Tags: monaco-editor

Is it possible to create a new language:

```
monaco.languages.register({ id: 'sql2' });
```

Inheriting all the configs from an already existing language ('sql' in this case)?

Basically, I want to create a new language to add some `completionProviders`, but I want to inherit all the default configs (syntax highlighting mostly) from the base 'sql' lang.

Answer (score 1):

That's possible, yes. Check the language definition files in Monaco (e.g. monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/mysql/mysql) and how they define keywords and syntax highlighting. You can create your own definition file and import existing files to re-use those. Here's a part of a language definition I wrote, which combines 4 languages into one:

```js
import { languages } from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api";

import { language as js } from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/javascript/javascript";
import { conf as tsConfig, language as ts } from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/typescript/typescript";
import { language as mysql } from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/mysql/mysql";
import { language as py } from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/python/python";

type IRichLanguageConfiguration = languages.LanguageConfiguration;
type ILanguage = languages.IMonarchLanguage;

export const languageConfiguration: IRichLanguageConfiguration = {
    ...tsConfig,
};

export const language: ILanguage = {
    defaultToken: "invalid",
    ignoreCase: false,

    typeKeywords: [], // We have no TS types.
    keywords: ts.keywords,

    operators: ts.operators,
    symbols: ts.symbols,
    escapes: ts.escapes,
    digits: ts.digits,
    octaldigits: ts.octaldigits,
    binarydigits: ts.binarydigits,
    hexdigits: ts.hexdigits,
    regexpctl: ts.regexpctl,
    regexpesc: ts.regexpesc,

    // Since we use also JS as sub language and we can only specify case sensitivity on a global level, we make
    // SQL case-insensitive by duplicating some symbols with lower case style.
    mysqlBrackets: mysql.brackets,
    mysqlKeywords: [
        ...mysql.keywords,
        ...(mysql.keywords as string[]).map((keyword) => { return keyword.toLowerCase(); }),
    ],
    mysqlOperators: [
        ...mysql.operators,
        ...(mysql.operators as string[]).map((operator: string) => { return operator.toLowerCase(); }),
    ],
...
```